# Заменить строку в C++

Tags: c++, строки

Есть строка

```
e.NEED_VERIFICATION=!0,e.VERSION="v0.3 (beta)",e.TEST_MODE=
```

Нужно найти в этой строке

```
e.VERSION="v<some text>"
```

Заменить `<some text>` на нужную строку например на "1.2.3"

Итог: `e.VERSION="v1.2.3"`

Comment: Находите, расчленяете на части, создаете заново...

Comment: @Harry А как найти строку если я не знаю какой <some text>? Могу без проблем найти e.VERSION="v. А как дальше? Скорее всего через регулярку нужно, да? Но в нем не силен

Comment: а дальше до закрывающей `"`

Comment: @user7860670 понимаю, но не знаю как

Comment: @Barlukov воспользуйтесь regex-ом. Это будет что-то типа: `<[^>]+>`

Comment: регулярка - \"(.*)\", достаете группу(строку), делаете replace

Comment: @punchel предлагаешь все вхождения "__" найти? их там тысячи или можно ли так String^ pattern = "e.VERSION="v(.*)\""; Говорю не силен в регулярках)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот, без всякой тяжелой артиллерии в виде regex...

```
string s = R"==(e.NEED_VERIFICATION=!0,e.VERSION="v0.3 (beta)",e.TEST_MODE=)==";

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    size_t start = s.find("e.VERSION=\"v");
    if (start != s.npos)
    {
        size_t stop =s.find("\"",start+12);
        if (stop != s.npos)
        {
            s.replace(start+12,stop-(start+12),"1.2.3");
            cout << s << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Брат, ты просто лучший!

Comment: @Barlukov [Скромно потупя глаза] Я знаю :)